# Detect network hardware

Tags: networking, kali-linux

When I tried to install Kali Linux, I encountered a little issue on its configuration. In `Detect network hardware`, it is indicated :

> Some of your hardware needs non-free firmware files to operate. The
>   firmware can be loaded from removable media, such as a USB stick or
>   floppy.
>
> The missing firmware files are iwlwifi-8000C-21.ucode
>   iwlwifi-8000C-20.ucode iwlwifi-8000C-19.ucode iwlwifi-8000C-18.ucode
>   iwlwifi-8000C-17.ucode iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode iwlwifi-8000C-15.ucode
>   iwlwifi-8000C-14.ucode iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode

Is it because Kali Linux hasn't been well installed on my external drive? What do I have to do?

P.S. So far the network configuration can't be autoconfigure. The only way it works is if I configure it manually.

Comment: You should put the missing firmware  on another  USB to be detected and loaded

Comment: Be careful not to cause duplicates between your questions.  This question actually answers your previous question which means that it is a duplicate.  You should remove this one and edit the previous one with this information as it is most relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because Kali Linux hasn't been well installed on my external drive? What do I have to do?

The `non-free` firmawre isn't included on the kernel

Download the missing firmware from [here](https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware/tree/master/firmware), copy it to your USB device the plug in your device and restart detection

Also you can skip this steps and install the `iwlwifi` later:

```
git clone https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware.git
cd /iwlwifi-firmware/firmware
cp iwlwifi-8000* /lib/firmware
```

Answer (score -1):

in which terminal we write this driver during installation.

> git clone https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware.git

> cd /iwlwifi-firmware/firmware

> cp iwlwifi-8000* /lib/firmware]

If there is no terminal in the installation process

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/422475)